# Reauthorizing the application in each request

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

I was able to properly configure the Facebook authentication. To test the failure flow of my app I just simply did not allow the app to authorize the FB user. It called `FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed` as expected and that's fine.

Problem occurs when I again need to authorize that app for the user. It never ever pops up the authorize dialog again even though I add `[FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];`.

I believe there should be a way to problematically prompt the authorization dialog to user as this is a login function.

However after that first unauthorized access I cannot ever authorize that user. Simply it returning,

> Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=2 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 2.)" UserInfo=0x1c5e4430 {com.facebook.sdk:ErrorLoginFailedReason=com.facebook.sdk:ErrorLoginFailedReason}

To reset things I deleted the app, removed derived data, restated the phone etc. Nothing worked for me yet. I'm sure that the way I have used FB SDK is correct since I am using that for the free version of my app. Same things is copied over to here.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the Facebook SDK, are you calling

```
[appDelegate openFacebookSessionWithAllowLoginUI:YES];
```

?

Comment: Yes I do with following.     [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:nil
                                       allowLoginUI:YES
                                  completionHandler:
     ^(FBSession *session,
       FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
         [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
     }];

Answer (score 0):

Are you running your app on IOS6?  If so, did you configure your FaceBook app (on facebook) with your iPhone app's bundle id?

Comment: Yes I am running under ios 6. Yes I did configure it.